# Google Cloud Policy Based Classic VPN configuration text file for Cisco ASA

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, cisco-vpn

I've created a Google Cloud Policy Based Classic VPN. The far end is a Cisco ASA and they have asked me to provide

> 'the configuration text file, because it will include the phase1 and 2
>   encryption and authentication protocols.'

This doesn't sound like an unreasonable request, but I can't find anywhere to obtain this data. Does it exist? (I know very little about VPNs....) or is the data available somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first have a look at [this](https://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=25474&seqNum=7) article. You can find details about [IPsec and IKE support](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview#ipsec_and_ike_support) in the documentation:

> - **Cloud VPN only supports a pre-shared key (shared secret) for authentication**. You must specify a shared secret when you create the
>     Cloud VPN tunnel. This same secret must be specified when creating the
>     tunnel at the peer gateway.
> - **For ciphers and configuration parameters supported by Cloud VPN**, see [Supported IKE ciphers](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers).

In addition, have a look at [Using third-party VPNs with Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/interop-guides):

> **Any third-party device or service that supports IPSEC and IKE versions 1 or 2 should be compatible with Cloud VPN**. For more
>   information, see [Supported IKE ciphers](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers).

there are some examples available. Step by step configuration guide available for [Cisco ASA 5505 with Classic VPN](https://cloud.google.com/files/CloudVPNGuide-UsingCloudVPNwithCiscoASA.pdf) (supports static routes only).

If something goes wrong you should check [Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/support/troubleshooting) guide.